# Error: unknown option "-state" occurs when running a script named button.tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I created a simple script to try out the Tk button widget but I encountered an unexpected error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require Tk

set w .demo
toplevel $w

ttk::button $w.ok -text OK -command {puts "OK Pressed"}
grid $w.ok
```

When I run this, I get two windows: one window that gets created by the `package require Tk` command called "button" in the title bar (because I named the script "button.tcl") and the other which is created by the `toplevel $w` command and is called "demo" in the title bar.

The "demo" top-level window behaves as expected. If I click the OK button it executes the script command.  The problem is, if I move my mouse inside the "button" window I get the following error dialog:

*Error: unknown option "-state"*

Details>>

```
unknown option "-state"
unknown option "-state"
    while executing
"$w cget -state"
    (procedure "tk::ButtonEnter" line 3)
    invoked from within
"tk::ButtonEnter ."
    (command bound to event)
```

[image: Failing button application with error message]

I am using ActiveTcl 8.6.4.1 and Windows 8. I also tried variations of running this, such as using the `wish` interpreter instead of `tclsh`, leaving off `package require Tk`, using other widgets instead, etc.

The only thing strange thing is, if I rename the script file to something other than "button.tcl", the error does not occur, which solves the immediate problem but still leaves me with questions:

1. Why does this error happen when the script happens to be called "button.tcl"?
2. If there is a potential problem with the using the name "button.tcl" for a script file, are there any other such file names that I should watch out for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From "Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk" by Brent B. Welch et al, page 476:

> *Don't use widget names for script names.*
>   The application class name becomes the class name for the main toplevel window. For example, if you use a script name like button.tcl, the class for . becomes Button. This causes it to inherit all the standard Button bindings and attribute values, which can cause problems in your application.

Looking inside `button.tcl` in the `tk8.6` library, the problem is apparent. This script binds the class `Button` and the `Enter` event to an invocation of `tk::ButtonEnter` with the window name as argument. Inside `tk::ButtonEnter`, the window is queried for its `-state` option value. Since your script is named `button.tcl`, this binding will be fired when the mouse enters your main window.

Comment: Also avoid naming images after the operations they do. Why? Because creating an image called `open` will make your program fail mysteriously, as you'll have replaced a standard Tcl command. (Been there, done that…)